# If you issue an http request from the chrome dev tools console, will it include the cookies of the page you're currently on?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

As an example, if I'm logged into stackoverflow and I use the `fetch` api in the chrome dev tools console to hit a stackoverflow.com endpoint, will my cookies from this domain be included?

Comment: Look at the network request....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. If you go to the *Network* tab, open the console, and simply run `fetch('https://stackoverflow.com')`, you can see a request appear in the Network list. From there you can click on the request and clearly see the Request Headers (including `Cookie:`, containing all your cookies sent) with a quick scroll-down, and Chrome will also give you a separate tab for viewing the cookies in a table.